# Falco pod is not working init:ImagePullBackOff

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, falco

I'm using helm chart of falco and here are the commands

```
helm repo add falcosecurity https://falcosecurity.github.io/charts
helm repo update
helm install falco falcosecurity/falco
```

Here's the output

```
  NAME          READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS   AGE
    
  falco-6hlvx   0/1     Init:ImagePullBackOff   0          4m19
```

Once I type describe pod to know the reason behind this status, I find these events

```
Events:

  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  22m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/falco-6hlvx to minikube
  Normal   Pulling    15m (x4 over 22m)     kubelet            Pulling image "docker.io/falcosecurity/falco-driver-loader:0.32.1"
  Warning  Failed     13m (x4 over 20m)     kubelet            Failed to pull image "docker.io/falcosecurity/falco-driver-loader:0.32.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded
  Warning  Failed     13m (x4 over 20m)     kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     12m (x7 over 20m)     kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    2m45s (x34 over 20m)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "docker.io/falcosecurity/falco-driver-loader:0.32.1"
```

Comment: I don't see a question here, but `ImagePullBackoff` means that Kubernetes is failing to pull the container image. This can be caused by Docker Hub rate limits, although I believe you would usually see a relevant error in the event log. It can also be caused by some other network problem: your error suggests a timeout. Maybe wait and try again later?

Comment: I deployed elastic stack within minikube and It's working properly, there is no issue related to the network or something else, all the pods of elk are in running status, unless this falco

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever this happens, try to pull the image directly using `minikube ssh docker pull` to obtain a better error message. Be aware that Docker Hub applies a [download rate limit](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit/) and you might have just hit it.